# laravel eloquent join where clause with sub query to use column name comparision not working

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am having issues with laravel eloquent join to compare date in where clause using sub query. below query gives me error unknown column `policy_periods`.`statecode` i am using this column in where clause of the join subquery for example **App\Elrd::where("state_code",'=',DB::raw(`policy_periods`.`statecode`))->where('date',"<=",$mod_rating_eff_date)->max('date')**

can you please give me an idea if any solution possible ?
i have already tried whereRaw, whereColumn but none of them is working.

```
 DB::table('policy_periods')
                 ->join('payrolls','payrolls.policy_period_id', '=', 'policy_periods.id')
                 ->leftjoin('elrds', function($join) use($mod_rating_eff_date)
                 {
                    $join->on('elrds.state_code', '=', 'policy_periods.statecode');
                    $join->on('elrds.class_code', '=', 'payrolls.code');                  
                    $join->where('elrds.date',App\Elrd::where("state_code",'=',DB::raw(`policy_periods`.`statecode`))->where('date',"<=",$mod_rating_eff_date)->max('date'));
                    
                 })                
                 ->select('payrolls.*','payrolls.elr as payrollelr','policy_periods.id as pid','policy_periods.policy_no',DB::raw('CONCAT(eff_date, "-", exp_date) as dateGroup'),'policy_periods.eff_date','policy_periods.exp_date','policy_periods.statecode as ratingeffPolicyYear','policy_periods.statecode','elrds.class_code','elrds.year','elrds.date','elrds.elr','elrds.dratio')                 
                 ->where('policy_periods.mod_id',$id)             
                 ->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I encounter such issue, the first thing I usually do is to determine if the generated query is what I wanted.
You should log your queries so that you can ensure it.
To do that, a possible solution is to add a log in your AppServiceProvider (in function boot):

```
DB::listen(function ($query) {
    Log::debug('query',[
        $query->sql,
        $query->bindings,
        $query->time
    ]);
});
```

That being said, where do these backticks come from?

```
DB::raw(`policy_periods`.`statecode`)
```

You could replace it with `DB::raw('policy_periods.statecode')`

Please tell me if it fixes your issue, or provide the generated SQL query if the problem is not fixed.

Comment: hi thanks for feedback but i tried same as you provided but still getting error
Unknown column 'policy_periods.statecode' in 'where clause'
mysql query shows:  select max(`date`) as aggregate from `elrds` where `state_code` = policy_periods.statecode and `date` <= 2021-01-01

Comment: Ok, then we know at least that the error occurs because the query is split in 2 queries by Eloquent.

Comment: And it comes from the introduced "where" statement in `App\Elrd::where(`. Try to simplify the join clause: it seems quite complex.

Comment: sorry can you please guide me the solution because my query is working perfect if i remove the where conditon which causes error. just need to correct the where condition only

Comment: Maybe, first of all what is the purpose of the "where" clause in your join? You have 3 different "where" on the same line, which make it quite difficult to understand.

Comment: i have three tables which are joining on different columns. in the where clause i am trying to use date which is less then the given date and max date from the resulted date.